# Get-ADGroup "myADgroup" -Properties myProperty - parse output & get only CN

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Get-ADGroup "myADgroup" -Properties myProperty
```

How to parse output & get only CN?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IbrEIQG.png @montonero

Comment: Please post your code (a [mcve] to be precise) as text in your question, not as a screenshot off-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want the Name of the AD Group:

```
Get-ADGroup -Identity <ADGroup> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

You could also get the full Distinguished Name and then filter on the CN if required. I'm not sure if that's what you need or if you just want the Name.